# Looping for algorithms stucking UI in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, async-await

I want to loop for the combination and the function which get called are time taking task.
My UI get stuck for 5 sec to 10 sec.

I tried async and await but not able to figure out how to manage with my looping structure.

Below is my foreach loop I'm using to loop an array :

```
     this.poss_Origin.forEach((value, index) => {
     
     if (this.poss_Origin[index][0] === "Frame_1") {
  console.log("this.poss_Origin here createVariants ", this.poss_Origin, " index ", index);

  this.Display_Variants(
    this.Frame_1(
      this.Pallet_Length,
      this.Pallet_Width,
      this.Case_Length,
      this.Case_Width,
      this.XPos,
      this.YPos,
      noOfSchemaCases,
      this.HWeighted,
      this.VWeighted,
      this.outsideLabelPrior,
      this.poss_Origin,
      index
    )
  );

  console.log("this.poss_Origin here createVariants downloadImage ", number);
  this.downloadImage("Var 1");
  number++;
}
// //Frame 2
if (this.poss_Origin[index][0] === "Frame_2") {
  console.log("this.poss_Origin here createVariants ", this.poss_Origin, " index ", index);

  this.Display_Variants(
    this.Frame_2(
      this.Pallet_Length,
      this.Pallet_Width,
      this.Case_Length,
      this.Case_Width,
      this.XPos,
      this.YPos,
      noOfSchemaCases,
      this.HWeighted,
      this.VWeighted,
      this.outsideLabelPrior,
      this.poss_Origin,
      index
    )
  );

  console.log("this.poss_Origin here createVariants downloadImage ");
  // this.downloadImage("Var "+number);
  this.downloadImage("Var 2");

  number++;
}
// //Frame_3
if (this.poss_Origin[index][0] === "Frame_3") {
  console.log("this.poss_Origin here createVariants ", this.poss_Origin, " index ", index);

  this.Display_Variants(
    this.Frame_3(
      this.Pallet_Length,
      this.Pallet_Width,
      this.Case_Length,
      this.Case_Width,
      this.XPos,
      this.YPos,
      noOfSchemaCases,
      this.HWeighted,
      this.VWeighted,
      this.outsideLabelPrior,
      this.poss_Origin,
      index
    )
  );

  console.log("this.poss_Origin here createVariants downloadImage ");
  // this.downloadImage("Var "+number);
  this.downloadImage("Var 3");

  number++;
}


      }
```

And so on .

Can anyone help how to call this looping function without stucking UI ?

Comment: How is this related to React? You haven't included the code for `Display_Variants` or `Frame_n` or `downloadImage` so we have no idea what's causing the bottleneck. What debugging have you done on that code to figure out where the problem is?

Comment: The function for frame and display varients are of 2k-3k lines . That is why not included . The UI get stuck . I want to make it async-await for the this.poss_origin loop.